# How to create a unstacked bar plot with dates in X axis?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, matplotlib

I'm trying to create an unstacked bar plot.

I had a lot of problems to extract the dates from the data frame to be able using the with major_locator, DayLocator, etc.

Important: Date start type is  datetime64[ns]

I tried many options to unstack the bars but I wasn't able to fix it.

```
fig, ax = plt.subplots(1,1, figsize=(15,8))
fig.suptitle('ICP: Time standing', fontsize=25, fontweight='bold')

date_listdate_list = df[df['Container'] == 1]['Date start'].tolist()


ax.bar(date_list,df[df['Container'] == 1]['Aluminum (Al)\nppb'],width = 0.1)
ax.bar(date_list,df[df['Container'] == 1]['Barium (Ba)\nppb'],width = 0.1)


myFmtx = DateFormatter("%d/%m")
ax.xaxis.set_major_locator(mdates.DayLocator(interval=1))
ax.xaxis.set_major_formatter(myFmtx)
fig.autofmt_xdate()
```

[output Graph](https://i.stack.imgur.com/isl6T.png)

[Dataframe](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HyAtX.png)

Comment: when you say "unstacked bar plot", do you expect both bars to be side by side? Right now the bars are not stacked, they simply overlap one another.

Comment: Also, Please provide mockup data, in particular check out [How to make good reproducible pandas examples](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20109391/how-to-make-good-reproducible-pandas-examples)

Comment: Yes, I expect the bars to be side by side.

Comment: @DizietAsahi do you have an idea what to do?

Comment: Please refer to the link in my previous comment and provide a toy dataset that is not an image